# Other world manga|MC is OP mage

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, isekai

Looking for a manga where the main character gets transported to another world as his character from a game. He is a mage, capable of using two swords and some martial arts. Got beard and gray cloak. He wakes up in a forest (almost gets raped by an orc or some similar creature) and spends two weeks there. After making it to the road he encounters a carriage attacked by bandits and wipes them out. Invited to a manor of nobles he saved, he starts to tutor a girl in magic. His magic circles look like some binary code.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for *Arafoo Kenja no Isekai Seikatsu Nikki*

> Satoshi Osako was a player of the VRRPG 『Sword and Sorcery』 who defeated the Evil God and died for his troubles. When he awoke again he found himself in a strange unknown forest. Furthermore he possessed his avatar’s body and abilities. In other words, he was a cheat. Can a 40 year old DT, live peacefully in this world?

The cloak and his twin swords as you mentioned are here, the scene below is just before the bandit attack.

[image: cloak and swords 1]
[image: cloak and swords 2]

I won't show the "animal love attack" but I assure you it is in this manga.